# How to remove a previously added decorator on a resource?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Does anyone here knows how to remove a particular decorator on a resource? I extended `org.eclipse.ui.decorators` to my project and created a class that implements `ILightweightLabelDecorator`. In the decorator class I tested if the entry was a project and other test before calling `decorator.addOverlay()`. I did not implemented the other functions such as `removeListener`, `isLabelProperty`, `dispose`, `addListener` since I currently do not see the use. 
Any idea, resources, comment on how to proceed would greatly help.

Code: decorator function

```
    QualifiedName decorator = new QualifiedName("decorator", "value");

    if (element instanceof IProject) {
        IProject res = (IProject) element;

        if (!res.isOpen()) {
            return;
        }

        String val = null;
        try {
            val = res.getPersistentProperty(decorator);

        } catch (CoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (val != null && val.equals(DecoratorState.ACTIVE)) {

            decoration.addOverlay(ImageDescriptor.createFromFile(MyDecorator.class, 
                    "/icons/sample.gif"), IDecoration.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
            decoration.addSuffix(" [Using Enhancement]");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is having that same issue, it can be fixed with `LabelProviderChangedEvent`